# Finite dimensional $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

If $P$ is a finite rank projection, $A$ is an infinite dimensional $C^*$ algebra, can we deduce that $PAP$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: What do you mean by $PAP$? Do you mean the set of operators of the form $PTP$, where $T\in A$? If so, it is finite-dimensional: this is a subspace of the space of mappings from $P(A)$ to $P(A)$, and both of those are finite dimensional by assumption.

Comment: @AshwinTrisal $PAP$ is fairly standard terminology.  What do you mean by $P(A)$?

Comment: The image of the finite rank operator $P$: $\{x\in A\,|\,\exists y\in A \text{ such that } P(y)=x\}$.

Comment: @AshwinTrisal When talking about finite-rank operators in a $C^\ast$-algebra $A$, one's implicitly viewing $A$ as a closed $\ast$-subalgebra of the $C^\ast$-algebra $B(H)$ of bounded operators on some Hilbert space $H$, so a finite-rank element of $A$ is one that has finite rank as an operator on $H$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the situation is that $A\subset B(H)$, $P\in B(H)$, with $P$ of finite-rank, then yes, $PAP$ is finite-dimensional.

One can construct an explicit isomorphism $PB(H)P=M_n(\mathbb C)$, where $n=\operatorname{Tr}(P)$ is the rank of $P$. It then follows that $PAP\subset PB(H)P$ is finite-dimensional.